# Online Mathematica, pros and cons, linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I apologize in advance if this question is irrelevant to this website.

I would like to use Mathematica to solve a system of linear equations with lots of unknowns(729 unknowns), the unknowns are tensor components of  curvature tensors arising from a differential geometry problem.

I would like to buy Mathematica for this  purpose and I have to decide between buying it online or installing the desktop version on a PC. I m thinking of buying the online version. I have the following questions:

1. What are the advantages and disadvantages of the desktop version over the online version ? For example, are there mathematical or programming functionalities which are available only on the desktop version and not in the online version ?
2. I assume that if I buy the online version, then I will get a username and a password to access an online version of mathematica from any computer. (Just like how one can type latex on overleaf.com from an online account using any PC). Is my assumption correct ?

3)Does Mathematica provide a user friendly way for solving linear simultaneous equations with lots of unknowns ? Let me elaborate with an example: Say I want to solve the simultaneous equations $x=2y+a, y-3x=7x+2$ for $x,y$. I would like a software where I can just type: $x=2y+a, y-3x=7x+2$ and ask the software to solve for $x,y$ and just give me the solution symbolically in terms of parameter $a$ instead of me having to rearrange terms so that the equations become $x-2y=a, y-10x=2$ and then write it in matrix form, then ask it to make a matrix inversion. The difference I am talking about might seem silly in this example but it will not be silly in my original problem where I have 700 unknowns. If this feature exists in Mathematica, it will save me a lot of time.

Thank you,

Comment: You may want to look at commands like Solve (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) or NSolve. If you can express things in the form of a matrix equation, likely LinearSolve would be useful.

Comment: 3) You'll just have to learn the syntax: `Solve[{x == 2 y + a, y - 2 x == 7 x + 2}, {x, y}]` works fine.

Comment: I find the online version very unstable. I can only recommend buying the software.

Comment: FYI, you can get a free 15-day trial of the desktop version at https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/ if you want to try it.